# Displaying data in a view when foreign key equals primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

I have two tables General_Info and Quantity. General_Info has a primary key QuoteID and has a one to many relationship with Quantity (FK = General_InfoQuotesID). In my details view I want to display a specific row from General_Info with the all of the data from Quantity where QuoteID from General_Info is equal to General_InfoQuotesID. My current attempt at this has a Details view set up to display the specified row data from General_Info with a partial view that holds the quantities. The issue I'm having, is that instead of showing the quantities that correspond to a given row in General_Info, it just displays all of the additional quantities ever added regardless of the row in General_Info it corresponds to.

Here's my model classes:

```
public partial class General_Info
{
    public General_Info()
    {
         this.Quantities = new HashSet<Quantity>();
    }

    public int QuoteID {get; set;}
    public System.DateTime Open_Quote {get; set;}
    public string Customer_Name {get; set;}
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Quantity> Quantities {get; set;}
}

public partial class Quantity
{
    public int QuantityID {get; set;}
    public int AdditionalQty {get; set;}
    public int General_InfoQuotesID {get; set;} //fk

    //navigation property
    public virtual General_Info General_Info {get; set;}
}
```

And then here's some of my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
{

    General_Info general_info = unitOfWork.General_Info_Repository.GetByID(id);
    return View(general_info);
}

[HttpGet]
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult DQuantities()
{
    IEnumerable<Quantity>quantities = unitOfWork.Quantity_Repository.Get();

    // from quantities, select additionalQty when
    // General_Info.PK == Quantities.FK
    var qtys = from q in quantities
               where q.General_Info.QuoteID == q.General_InfoQuotesID
               select q.AdditionalQty;
```

I don't think this line is right, but I tried it after trying to load the linq statement directly into the partial view didn't work

```
    qtys = qtys.ToList(); 

    return PartialView(qtys);
}
```

And then in my DQuantities view (I didn't include the details view because that's already working properly, and I don't think that that's where the problem is anyway)

```
@model IEnumerable<SourceMvc.Quantity>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      Additional Quantities:
    </th>
  </tr>
```

pretty sure this foreach statement is just targeting
the actual table data from IEnumerable which
is why its printing all of the quantities as apposed
to just targeting the data picked up by my linq statement

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
  <tr>
    <td>
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AdditionalQty)
    </td>
  </tr>
}
</table>
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: Why don't you use the `public virtual ICollection<Quantity> Quantities {get; set;}` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've got a working answer.

In my controller I changed the DQuantities to:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult DQuantities(int id = 0)
    {
        General_Info general_info = unitOfWork.General_Info_Repository.GetByID(id);

        IEnumerable<Quantity> getQuantities = unitOfWork.Quantity_Repository.Get();

        IEnumerable<Quantity> qtys = getQuantities.Where(q => q.General_InfoQuotesID == general_info.QuoteID);

        return PartialView(qtys);   
    }
```

And then in my partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<SourceMvc.Quantity>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AdditionalQty)
    </th>
  </tr>

  @foreach ( var item in Model)
  {
    <tr>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AdditionalQty)
      </td>
    </tr>
  }

</table>
```